# Change the tab order of radio button groups in Html Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

If I have two radio button groups (grouped using the *name* attribute) on a webpage, is it possible to alter the order in which they are moved though when using the TAB key?

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="1">One<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="2">Two<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="3">Three<br/>
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="a">A<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="b">B<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="c">C<br/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Wholesaler/4xqcoz3p/

In the markup above, I have two groups. When TAB is pressed the upper group will be focused and when pressed again focus moves to the lower group. My query is whether this default order can be overridden so that the lower group is focused first.

To clarify, I do not want to be able to TAB between the individual radio buttons in each group, just change the tab order for the groups they belong to.

Comment: This is not `winforms`, it is html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabIndex` is there for that purpose.

check the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/stdeepak22/r3sphzvf/

Comment: This works for the first two TAB presses, but a third press moves focus to the B option of the second group. Adding tabindex="-1" removes them from the order completely, even if they are selected.